# publish angular2 with webpack application on public server

Tags: angular, webpack, lumen

I find some demo and want to make with that angular2 application. I start with [this demo](http://anvel.io/) which use angular2, webpack and lumen as backend api. I see that I can run it localy when run

> php artisan run

but I can't find the way how to run it in shared hosting (like hostgator). Did maybe anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone need it. Publish all files included public files when run webpack but before change in env file that APP_ENV=production and all works in public servers. TNX to all!